# Python to run executables and give child command to it

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to create a script that runs different action in shell. Such as I can run sqlite3 via

```
os.system('sqlite3')
```

Then sqlite> appears in my terminal. Now how do I run undermentioned command from python script?

```
sqlite> .open db.sqlite3
sqlite> .table
sqlite> .modes on
sqlite> .column True
sqlite> select * from table_name
```

I want all these actions from python script automatically.
I searched a lot of tutorials find some subprocesses but thay did not meet my requirements.

My OS is Debian 10, Python version is 3.7
Thank You

Comment: Python has the [standard library APIs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) to interact with `sqlite3`.

Comment: connect('db.sqlite3')?

Comment: `import sqlite3;conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')` will create a Connection object that represents the database

Comment: I know that, but what if I want to run from shell. I need it for doing some automations.

Comment: Huh? If you are automating, you must surely know the commands you want to enter in order to be able to automate... so why do you need a shell?

Comment: So it's impossible to do?

Comment: It's not impossible at all. I, and others, am merely trying to understand what you are trying to do before offering our best advice. At the moment though, it is hard to advise because your needs aren't clear. You appear to either know, or not know, what commands you want to enter.

Comment: I know the commands what have to be entered, But do not know how to enter.

Comment: Ok, if you know the commands, use the standard API  as @AbdulNiyasPM suggested,  and you don't need a shell. If you don't know how to use the standard API, edit your question to show the commands and doubtless someone will help you work out how to submit them.

Comment: Please give me a solution to run a child command in shell that's all.

Comment: I know subprocess can do it, But how to do I don't know

Comment: You probably want something like `gnome-terminal -e "sqlite3 db.sqlite3"`

Comment: It will open the db, then I want to run .table command, then .modes on .then .column True finally show all rows from a table. I want these process automatically from python script and execute in the shell. Thank You

Comment: Try `gnome-terminal -e 'sqlite3 db.sqlite3 -cmd ".table" ".modes On" ".column True" "select * from tablename"'`

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. os.system('sqlite3 db.sqlite3 -cmd ".table" ".mode column" ".headers on" "select * from tablename"')